# X pages build issue in lotus domino 8.5.2

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I am using Lotus Notes 8.5.2 and using x pages in one of my project. Do we need to build the project every time we make changes in custom controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build when you want to test your changes.

So you do not have to build the project every time you make changes, but whenever you want to test your changes.

Building the project tells Domino Designer to compile the source code (your XPages, custom controls etc.) into Java byte-code. It is the Java byte-code that the Domino server runs when you access your application.